# AWS Python lambda: pip install requirements.txt with --no-deps

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk, aws-lambda-layers

Using AWS CDK v2, I want to deploy two [lambda functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk.aws_lambda_python_alpha/PythonFunction.html). As both depend on *pandas*, I want to deploy a [layer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk.aws_lambda_python_alpha/PythonLayerVersion.html) first, which has *pandas* and its dependencies in `requirements.txt` located at `entry`.

One of the lambda functions also depends on *pyarrow*, which I put into the `requirements.txt` located at `entry` of that lambda function. As both *pyarrow* and *pandas* depend *numpy*, I currently end up with *numpy* and its dependencies being installed both in the layer and that lambda function, which obviously isn't what I want.

In the end, I'm looking for a way to pass `--no-deps` to the `pip` installation of `requirements.txt` of the lambda function that depends on *pyarrow*. Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried using `pyarrow --no-deps` in your `requirements.txt` file?

Comment: I tried that after you suggested it: "ERROR: Invalid requirement: pyarrow==8.0.0 --no-deps" But it seems as if the feature might be available soon?! https://github.com/pypa/pip/pull/10837

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible to specify `no-deps` when using a requirements.txt.  CDK also can use `pipenv`'s `Pipfile` and [Poetry](https://python-poetry.org/docs/)'s `poetry.lock`.  That being said, in my research none of those tools seem to support installing with `--no-deps` either unless you manually mess with the lock files (not advised or maintainable really).

Looking deeper at the specific problem, I don't see `pyarrow` listing `pandas` as a dependency but I do see it installing `numpy` which is a dependency of `pandas`

I think your best option presently is to just deal with having `numpy` in both places or put both `pyarrow` and `pandas` in the layer.

Comment: Oh, you're absolutely right, *numpy* is a dependency of *pyarrow*, not *pandas*, will change that in the question.

Comment: The following feature might be able to solve the problem -- do you agree? https://github.com/pypa/pip/pull/10837 I'd still prefer an additional argument `without_dependencies` or so by which  `--no-deps` may be set on `python3 -m pip install...` where that command is executed on the lambda's `requirements.txt`.

Comment: Yes, it looks like that would do it